# Next.JS API routes accessed openly - CORS not blocking?

Tags: next.js, cors, vercel

I tried to add CORS for a Next app running on Vercel using the following:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            value:
              process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "production"
                ? process.env.VERCEL_URL
                : "localhost:3000",
          },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

However I can still Postman to any of my `/api/*` routes and access the data. What am I doing wrong here? How do I make it so only same origin is allowed?

I also tried with https in the path:

```
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            value:
              process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "production"
                ? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`
                : "http://localhost:3000",
          }
```

I read the docs.
I also tried with https in the path:

```
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            value:
              process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "production"
                ? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`
                : "http://localhost:3000",
          }
```

I just want to limit api calls to same origin.

Comment: CORS's purpose is not to block anything. Rather, it's meant to relax the SOP's restrictions.

Comment: You can `curl` to any APIs available on the internet. A browser using it, however, is another history. You need to carefully review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS